# creating an event on facebook

Tags: php, events, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem in my code, when i press create event nothing happens, here's the code in php:

```
<?php
$app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$my_url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // mainly this should be the same URL to THIS page

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&scope=create_event";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
. "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
. "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

if( !empty($_POST) && (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['start_time']) || empty($_POST['end_time'])) ) {
    $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
} elseif(!empty($_POST)) {
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?" . $access_token;
    $params = array();
    // Prepare Event fields
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        if(strlen($value))
            $params[$key] = $value;

    // Check if we have an image
    if( isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES['picture']['name']) ) {
        $uploaddir = './upload/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            $params['picture'] = "@" . realpath($uploadfile);
        }
    }  

    // Start the Graph API call
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    /*
        Next option is only used for
        user from a local (WAMP)
        machine. This should be removed
        when used on a live server!

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/7

    */
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $decoded = json_decode($result, true);
    curl_close($ch);
    if(is_array($decoded) && isset($decoded['id'])) {
        // Event created successfully, now we can
        // a) save event id to DB AND/OR
        // b) show success message AND/OR
        // c) optionally, delete image from our server (if any)
        $msg = "Event created successfully: {$decoded['id']}";
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create An Event</title>
<style>
label {float: left; width: 100px;}
input[type=text],textarea {width: 210px;}
#msg {border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php if( isset($msg) ) { ?>
<p id="msg"><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <p><label for="name">Event Name</label><input type="text" name="name" value="a" /></p>
    <p><label for="description">Event Description</label><textarea name="description"></textarea></p>
    <p><label for="location">Location</label><input type="text" name="location" value="" /></p>
    <p><label for="">Start Time</label><input type="text" name="start_time" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>" /></p>
    <p><label for="end_time">End Time</label><input type="text" name="end_time" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"))); ?>" /></p>
    <p><label for="picture">Event Picture</label><input type="file" name="picture" /></p>
    <p>
        <label for="privacy_type">Privacy</label>
        <input type="radio" name="privacy_type" value="OPEN" checked='checked'/>Open&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="privacy_type" value="CLOSED" />Closed&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="privacy_type" value="SECRET" />Secret&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Create Event" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? do you get some sort of error? Please provide more information.

Comment: when i fill the informations about event name description etc... then i press create event it didn't create anythin' and no error occured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens if the token is not returned. This is the case when `file_get_contents` is not working properly. To make sure that this function treats url as a file, you need to make sure that it is configured under php.ini as follows "allow_url_fopen = 1"

Answer (score 0):

It seems the action="" of your form is empty ? ...

Comment: aha ok you are right, what suppose to be the action in this case

Comment: and i get the code from here : http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-create-facebook-events-using-graph-api-advanced/59/

Comment: Its too bad you are copying code without understanding it :) Anyways the action should be the location of the PHP file processing the data - In this situation if your file is x.php, the action should be the same - x.php

Comment: Haha Dear if the action attribute is empty then it should return the same page

Comment: And yet, you say "nothing happens", so something is indeed wrong. Is your file even located on a PHP Server... ? If yes, make sure you have display_errors on and error_reporting of E_ALL (just for debugging purposes).

Comment: This... Is more than a year old... How is this comment useful ? :) just for the sake of commenting?